# Is there a name for non-reflexive "equivalence" relation?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations, math-history

An equivalence relation $a \sim b$ is a binary relation which is symmetric, transitive, and reflexive.

What if I give up on reflexiveness?

I mean, in the set where the binary operation $\sim$ is defined, there's at least one element $a$ such that $a \nsim a$ (and at least one element $b$ for which $b \sim b$, because I'm not talking of an irreflexive relation).

### **Does such a relation have a name in mathematics?**

**I'm not asking for examples of such a relation**

Comment: Note that in such a relation, if $x \sim y$, then $x\sim x$ and $y\sim y$.  That is, it's an equivalence relation on the subset of elements which are related to another.

Comment: If there *is any* $x$ where there is no $y$ such that $x\sim y$, then clearly $x\nsim x$ and so therefore the relation will not be reflexive. Thus transivity and symmetry do not entail reflexivity.

Comment: I see that you make your edits to make it clear that you are looking for a name and not examples, bu I think that what the examples should tell you is that this notion is so close to equivalence relations that I don't think anyone has ever bothered giving it a name. Is there a point in studying a class of relations which are basically equivalence relations + a subset of "isolated points"? It's also equivalent to studying equivalence relations endowed with a distinguished class (by declaring all the "isolated points" to be equivalent and a distinguished class). So I don't think it has a name.

Comment: @CaptainLama, ok, I guess yours could well be an answer. I hadn't really thought that the difference between the relation I described and a proper equivalence relation was so thin and irrelevant. I mean, I was using it as it was an equivalence relation (to give some context, I was using it to partition a set), but I thought the difference could be relevant. I see now that it's just a matter of attaching unique identifiers to the isolated points, so that they are clearly not equal to each other.

Comment: A symmetric transitive relation is also known as a partial equivalence relation (PER).